# How to generate an MD5 password string hash in JavaScript or Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, md5

I need to write a function to generate an md5 hash for a password on a site page. Help write the md5 function?

For example:

```
function handleEvent() {
   var md5 = generateMD5(document.getElementById("password").value);
   console.log(md5);
}

function generateMD5(string) {
   // generate md5 hash here
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use bcrypt instead? I believe it's more secure than md5

Comment: BTW: You should not rely on client side crypto functions. This should be done on the server side/backend

Comment: As stated before this shouldn't be handled client side, but more importantly MD5 is very outdated and insecure for passwords use bcrypt instead or even better use an auth provider

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the already written md5 generation function: [GitHub](https://github.com/simetrio/md5-js-tools) ([npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/md5-js-tools), [Demo](https://www.olrix.net/tools/md5-generator/))

Using script tag:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/md5-js-tools@1.0.2/lib/md5.min.js"></script>
<script>
   var hash = MD5.generate("Example string");
   console.log(hash);
</script>
```

With ES5:

```
import { MD5 } from "md5-js-tools";
var hash = MD5.generate("Example string");
console.log(hash);
```

or

```
const { MD5 } = require("md5-js-tools");
var hash = MD5.generate("Example string");
console.log(hash);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="md5.min.js"></script>
<script>
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var strHash = md5('tutsplus');
    alert('The MD5 hash of the tutsplus string is:' + strHash);
});
</script>
```

Ref: For more details follow the [link](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-hash-and-decrypt-with-md5-in-javascript--cms-38297)